# Zend DB: How to find the actual amount of affected rows with INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Tags: mysql, zend-db

$db->update() returns the affected amount of rows.

There is no Zend_DB method for insert ... on duplicate key update ..., so one should use the query() method:

$result = $db->query('INSERT INTO table(key, field) SELECT val1, val2 FROM table as t2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field = VALUES(field)');

To find out the amount of affected or inserted records:
$result->rowCount()

But this method also counts all the records that were updated with the same value.

I need to know all of the actual affected (changed) records.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the "On Duplicate Key Update" causes  ROW_COUNT() or mysql_rows_affected() to  report rows with multiple updates, it is not a count of UNIQUE rows that are updated.

Comment: The two strategies that I use are A) follow the 'on-dup-key' query with a select against the table with criteria that defines a unique record.  B) compare the count the records before/after the 'on-dup-key' query.